# Passing values to other methods

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to pass a value from one Method to the other so I can compare two numbers. But I can't get the number from the first method to the second one. To be more exact, I would like to get the value of `rowsBeforeFilterApplied` from method `CheckReports()` to the second method `VerifyFilterFunctionality()` so I could use the Assert and compare both values.

In the current setup, the problem is that

> rowsBeforeFilterApplied does not exist in the current context.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
public void CheckReports()
{
    int rowsBeforeFilterApplied = SeleniumDriver.ChromeDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr")).Count;
}

      

public void VerifyFilterFunctionality()
{
    int rowsWhenFilterApplied = SeleniumDriver.ChromeDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr")).Count;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);//SLEEP

           
    Assert.Greater(rowsBeforeFilterApplied, rowsWhenFilterApplied);
}
```

Comment: Are both methods in the same class?

Comment: Which method do you want to call?

Comment: Values are passed to a method using [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods)

Comment: "Pass" involves parameters. Your methods have no parameters and you're not calling one method from the other. It looks like you need a *field* in the class so that both methods can access it. Learn about variable scope.

Comment: yes, they are in the same class. I would just like to do the Assert.Greater(rowsBeforeFilterApplied, rowsWhenFilterApplied);
But rowsBeforeFilterApplied is in a different method than rowsWhenFilterApplied. So I get error for rowsBeforeFilterApplied - 'The name does not exist in the current context'

Comment: Can you add more explicit details please?  Describe **in words** what you want to do, since the code alone does not convey your intention yet.  Be specific about which values, which methods and how each is to be called.  Who calls VerifyFilterFunctionality?  You may need to add a field to the containing class if the signatures cannot be changed if these are framework functions.  I'd like to know a little bit more about the bigger picture before suggesting a solution.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the variables globally??

Comment: @Kalfja don't just answer questions of clarification in the comments of your own question.  Edit the question to improve it to include the missing information.

Answer (score -3):

```
public int CheckReports()
    { 
        
        int rowsBeforeFilterApplied = SeleniumDriver.ChromeDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr")).Count;

return rowsBeforeFilterApplied 
    }

public void VerifyFilterFunctionality()
    {    
         int rowsBeforeFilterApplied = CheckReports();
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);//SLEEP
         int rowsWhenFilterApplied = SeleniumDriver.ChromeDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr")).Count;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);//SLEEP

       
         Assert.Greater(rowsBeforeFilterApplied, rowsWhenFilterApplied);
    }
```

**You also can declare both variable globally**

Comment: Why call the selenium driver twice?

Comment: That won't work. The call to CheckReports will get the value in the "after" state, not the "*before*" state that it's intended to get.

Comment: int rowsBeforeFilterApplied = CheckReports()

will it work if moving above line to 1st line of second method?
Also tried with declaring global variables?

Comment: Doubtful. Ostensibly, these methods are called independently, with some user action taking place in between them to change the state.